# sql server cursor comparison

Tags: sql-server, cursor

i have 2 cursor in which cursor 1 has `select * from table 1` and cursor 2 has `select * from table 2`. I need to compare 2 cursors and if the fetched row in the cursor 1 is not equal to fetched row of cursor 2, then i wants to delete that fetched row from table 2. Please help me how to do this?

Comment: Seriously: get rid of the cursors! You can do this **much more easily and efficiently** with set-based operations like [`EXCEPT and INTERSECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXCEPT` to identify the changed rows.

```
;WITH DirtyRows AS
(
    SELECT * FROM [Table 1]
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM [Table 2]
)
DELETE [Table 2]
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM DirtyRows
    WHERE DirtyRows.Id = [Table 2].Id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that with cursors?, If I understood you correctly, you can just do:

```
DELETE B
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B
ON A.Id = B.Id
WHERE A.column1 <> B.column1 OR A.column2 <> B.Column2 ....
```

Or something like that.